# R: convert character string to function argument

Tags: r

I want to know, if there is a general way to convert character strings to object names that are recognized by functions as for example `merge()` or `write.table()`.

For example, I have many data frames to be passed to the combined `Reduce` `merge` function.

Since I don't want to write all the names by hand, I tried the following code:

```
# some data
d1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2", "3"),
                 A = c(1.1, 2.2, 2.4), 
                 B = c(11.7, 10.2, 9.6))

d2 <- data.frame(ID = c("9","11", "18"),
                 A = c(1.8, 1.2, 1.4), 
                 B = c(11.9, 10.5, 9.1))

d3 <- data.frame(ID = c("10","13", "15"),
                 A = c(1.0, 1.5, 1.6), 
                 B = c(10.3, 11.5, 12.1))

# generate names
d_names <- sprintf("d%d",seq(1:3))

# pass vector with names to the function
dat <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
              list(noquote(paste(as.character(d_names), collapse = ", "))))
```

It doesn't work with `noquote()`. The resulting data frame should look like this.

```
dat <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
              list(d1, d2, d3))
```

How can I transform the character vector into `d1, d2, d3` so that the function recognizes it as the names of the different data frames?

Is there a general way for transforming character strings into "input objects" that are recognized by functions, as for example for `write.table()`?

```
for (i in 1:length(d_names)) {

  write.table(x = paste0(d_names[i]), file = paste0("path/path/", d_names[i], ".txt"), sep = "\t", 
              col.names = TRUE)

}
```

How can I substitute the expression `x = paste0(d_names[i])` so that the actual objects `d1`, `d2` and `d3` will be recognized by `write.table()` and by `merge()`?

Comment: You might try `mget(d_names)` as a starting point.

Comment: and do `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), mget(d_names))`

Comment: I was looking for a more general answer, how to convert a character string into an object, that can also be taken as an input for the `write.table()` or other functions. Is there a general way of converting character strings to "input objects"?

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `mget` and creates the variable names with `paste`.

```r
# some data
d1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2", "3"),
                 A = c(1.1, 2.2, 2.4), 
                 B = c(11.7, 10.2, 9.6))

d2 <- data.frame(ID = c("9","11", "18"),
                 A = c(1.8, 1.2, 1.4), 
                 B = c(11.9, 10.5, 9.1))

d3 <- data.frame(ID = c("10","13", "15"),
                 A = c(1.0, 1.5, 1.6), 
                 B = c(10.3, 11.5, 12.1))

dat1 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
               list(d1, d2, d3))

dat2 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
              mget(paste("d", 1:3, sep = "")))

identical(dat1, dat2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>